# Why does my simple application stop

Tags: android

I am new to learning android development and I am following [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) to make a small application. I just changed a bit of code. and when I click the send button, i get a prompt saying "Unfortunately this My First App has stopped." Can somebody please tell me whatever is the matter.

I replaced the code given in the tutorial (here shown as a block comment in the code of second class), and replaced by the code which is here made prominent with comments containing *******.

FIRST ACTIVITY: -

```
package com.practice.firstapp1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.practice.firstapp1.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE= "com.practice.fristapp1.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id1);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

LAYOUT OF FIRST ACTIVITY: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

CODE OF 2ND ACTIVITY: -

```
    package com.practice.firstapp1;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

            // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                // Show the Up button in the action bar.
                getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            }

            //Get the intent which invoked this activity and read its extra's data into the string named message.
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_2); //************
            textView.setText(message);//***********

            setContentView(textView);//***********
//The above three statements along with statements from its layout (which have been given *s in comments have been placed instead of the statements in the following block comment. Because I wanted to create the TextView in layout.xml and handle its work in code.

/*
    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
*/

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

LAYOUT OF 2ND ACTIVITY: -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" >

    <TextView    <!--//*********************************-->
        android:id="@+id/text_view_2"    <!--//***********************-->
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"    <!--//**********************-->
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    <!--//**************-->
        android:textSize="40sp" />    <!--//**************************-->


</RelativeLayout>
```

---

ANDROID MANIFEST FILE : -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.practice.firstapp1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.practice.firstapp1.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.practice.firstapp1.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.practice.firstapp1.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.practice.firstapp1.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you post the error from the logcat please ?

Comment: have you declared the activities in manifest file? post manifest file

Comment: and you don't need this `setContentView(textView);`

Comment: @Raghunandan: I havn't done anything in the manifest file. I think it is done automatically when we are using eclipse. See here [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) 
**When you use the Eclipse tools to create the activity, it creates a default entry.**

Comment: @ZouZou: I don't even know what logcat is. If you can say how to, then I will.

Comment: Without seeing the logcat error result, how can we determine where the problem is?

Comment: @user2882662 you need to make an entry of the second activity is manifest which eclipse does not do for you. so i suggest you post the manifest file

Comment: @user2882662 your forget to look at the add it to manifest topic in the same link

Comment: @user2882662 post the manifest file to confirm

Comment: @user2882662 in eclipse goto windows  open perspective open other choose ddms click logcat you should see a caused by part. select and save the log to some text file. there is black button that says export log to text file at the top right. now copy paste the same here.

Comment: @user2882662 i can't seem to find anything wrong with the code  can you pls post the manifest file or confirm if you have an entry of the second activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments

```
I havn't done anything in the manifest file. I think it is done automatically when we are using eclipse.
```

Yes eclipse does add the activity to manifest if you create a new Android Activity.

Your manifest looks fine. Remove the below line

Edit 1 :

```
setContentView(textView);
```

`activity_display_message.xml` already has a textview and in your code you initialize your textView and set text. TextView already has a parent.

No need for `setContentView(textView)`

Comment: @user2882662 ok post the logcat. In Eclipse goto windows-->open perspective-->open other-->choose ddms click logcat you should see an exception post the same here and there is no harm is posting manifest file just for confirmation

Comment: Please see my two answers below for the log cat and manifest. I didnot know how to add an image in a comment.

Comment: @user2882662 run the app again select com.example.firstapp in devices top left of the screen shot posted. now check the log cat. in the logcat you see at the right a black button select the exception lines and save it to text file to a location of your choice . now copy paste the same here. and remember to edit your post not answer your question with another question

Comment: @user2882662 and remove `setContentView(textView)` and try. don't need that. i think this is your cause for as the child textview already has a parent.

Comment: @user2882662 what happens now did you remove this line `setContentView(textView)` and try? it should work

Comment: There is no com.example.firstapp in devices. Can you please try the code on your computer. It is not even runnng properly. I am getting this warning.

"[2013-11-04 01:00:40 - MyFirstApp1] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front"

Comment: To my surprise, I have only removed the extra setContentView() and restarted the emulator, it has run properly

Comment: "@user2882662 run the app again select com.example.firstapp in devices top left of the screen shot posted. now check the log cat. in the logcat you see at the right a black button select the exception lines and save it to text file to a location of your choice . now copy paste the same here. and remember to edit your post not answer your question with another question – Raghunandan"
I didnt do any of this. I couldn't even find com.example.firstapp in devices, but it has worked properly. So it is cool now? or am I supposed to get into any logcat matters?